Gurobi solver chooses lower value than expected
In my gurobi code i have the two following constraints:
Constraint (12-1)
    for j in J:
        for r in R:
            model.addConstr((
                B[j, 1, r] <= C_r[r] - (tt[i_CD][i_in][j_emp] + tt[i_in][1 + 1][j + 1]) +
                    (2 - gp.quicksum(x[j, j_prime, 1] for j_prime in J_ext if j_prime != j) -
                     gp.quicksum(y_0[j, 1, r_prime] for r_prime in R)) * M
            ), name="ct.12.1")

Constraint (13)
    # Battery bounds
    for r in R:
        for j in J:
            for i in I_ext:
                model.addConstr((B[j, i, r] <= C_r[r]), name="ct.13.1")
                model.addConstr((B[j, i, r] >= 0), name="ct.13.2")

Unfortunately the solver does not choose the expected value of 491.86 but instead chooses 5.52 (a way lower value). My model.lp file does show me the following (correct) calculation:
 ct.12.1: 10000 y_0[2,1,1] + 10000 x[2,0,1] + 10000 x[2,1,1]
   + 10000 x[2,3,1] + B[2,1,1] <= 20491.86

The solver therefore chooses a feasible but not exact solution. This constraint is not influenced by any others forcing it to have a lower value.

Have you definitely set the objective to be maximized?

No, the objective is to minimize.

If the solution is feasible and has a value of 5.52, then why do you expect the optimal solution to be 491.86 if you're minimizing?

because this is not the value i'm minimizing. this value should always stay at the upper bound of the feasible solution, which would consequently minimize my objective function

Try fixing whatever value you think it should be via upper and lower bounds on that variables.  You'll either get an infeasible model, or a result that is no better.  Either way I expect there will be a valuable lesson in there.

That is exactly the weird part. when i increase the lower bound i do get the expected feasible solution. Thats the thing i do not understand

Did it produce a solution with a better objective value?
